# Is there any way I can dynamically select a mirror that is closest to me?

Tags: repository, downloads, mirrors

Is a mirror automatically selected for downloads based on location, or is there a way to do it dynamically?

Comment: You could make a script that pings the servers, and then, choose the server with lowest ping among them.

Comment: https://www.unixmen.com/find-fastest-mirror-debian-derivatives/